# How do we calculate the directional derivative of of $g(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction of the vector $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> How do we calculate the directional derivative of of $g(x,y)$ at $(x,y)$ in the direction of the vector $(a,b)$

I have this problem I want to solve, but I am generalising it and asking on Math Stack Exchange, because I don't want anyone to do my specific homework problem.

I just want the general information such as what do they really want in this question and the steps to solving this.

Comment: Assuming you know how to evaluate partial derivatives, [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) seems to cover what you want.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Oh yes I know how to evaluate partial derivatives. Thanks alot for the link :)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 what does the upside down triangle mean?

Comment: $$\nabla = \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}, \dots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right)$$ is a shorthand for the operator that spits out the vector of partial derivatives w.r.t. the coordinate variables.

Comment: This is really something that should be covered in your textbook. Are you skimping on the reading?

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks :)

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I dont own a textbook :/